# What MySQL activity eats CPU?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have noticed weird CPU consumption peaks for MySQL process. When I monitor running queries, it's empty or some reasonable queries being executed. How do I better address the problem?

Is there a tool, which can monitor MySQL getting into CPU peak and dump stats on running queries to some log?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many 3rd party tools, most popular are

1. [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)
2. [MONyog for DBAs](https://www.webyog.com/)
3. [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit)

Both MONyog and MySQL Enterprise Monitor shows CPU usage information in Linux systems

However, if we tune certain parameters in my.cnf, high MySQL CPU usage may reduce

```
innodb_read_io_threads
innodb_write_io_threads
innodb_log_buffer_size
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
query_cache_size=0
```

Comment: Also the slowlog.